# Using NSTableView insertRowsAtIndexes

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I'm trying to add rows to my NSTableView dynamically using 
NSTableView::insertRowsAtIndexes:withAnimation

To do so, I update the contents of the NSArray that holds my data source, and then

```
[myTableView beginUpdates];
NSRange theRange = NSMakeRange(0, [self.myTableContents count]-1);
NSIndexSet* theIndexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:theRange];
[myTableView insertRowsAtIndexes:theIndexSet withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationEffectFade];
[myTableView endUpdates];
```

My problem is that I get a bounds error as the table redraws, and calculates the height of each row. The problem, I think, is mentioned in the documentation: "The numberOfRows in the table view is automatically increased by the count of indexes."

If I have 10 items in myTableContents, and I call insertRowsAtIndexes for all 10 of those items, then heightOfRow is called for rows 0-19 (the 10 rows in myTableContents, plus another 10 added as a result of calling insertRowsAtIndexes).

So, how do other tables handle this?

Answer (score 3):

theRange should only consists of the range of the new rows that are to be inserted.  i.e for `insertRowsAtIndexes:`  you should pass the indexes of the new rows that you are inserting not all the rows.

Your datasource should also be updated by that time and `numberOfRows` should reflect that.

Comment: Thanks! In the code example, I'm populating the table on startup, thus I'm adding *all* the items in the model (myTableContents) to the view at once. numberOfRows simply reports the size of the data source, which is fine when I simply call reloadData, but when I use insertRowsAtIndexes, the tableView adds the number of rows it got from numberOfRows to the number of items in my NSIndexSet, and then calls heightOfRow that many times (once for each row). Thus, the problem is that inserRowsAtIndexes is increasing the row count beyond what the dataSource contains. How do I fix that?

Comment: If myTableContents represents complete items, NSRange theRange = NSMakeRange(0, [self.myTableContents count]-1); is reflecting to that many rows. Lets say if you have 10 objects in your model. and u inserted 2 more at indexes 3,4.  The range should only consists of 3,4 and numberOfRows: method should return 12 now.

Comment: Assume numberOfRowsInTableView always returns [myTableContents count]. To insert two new rows, I first update the data source (myTableContents), and then call insertRowsAtIndexes, to update the TableView. To use your example, myTableView has 10 items, I add 2 more, and then instead of calling reloadData, I call insertRowsAtIndexes for those two new items. At that point, the NSTableView thinks it has 12 items, not 10, because it's internal row count was augmented by the call to insertRowsAtIndexes.

Answer (score 1):

Reload Table first time and after that use this..

```
[myTableView beginUpdates];  
NSIndexSet* theIndexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[self.myTableContents count]-1];
[myTableView insertRowsAtIndexes:theIndexSet withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationEffectFade];
[myTableView endUpdates];
```