# OSX NSTableView insertRowAtIndexes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

i already checked [Using NSTableView insertRowsAtIndexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892829/using-nstableview-insertrowsatindexes)  solution but It does not solve my problem.
i want insert row in nstableview at particular index(add dynamically)
index Set is valid, still it causes Program crash

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet=[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:i];
[myTableView insertRowsAtIndexes:indexSet withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationEffectFade];
```

1)is any thing wrong in my code?
2)Is there any another way to add row at particular index(add dynamically)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got My mistake.....  problem In other Code so This code is fine
But I want to add some points About   **insertRowsAtIndexes:** method
Hope it will helps to other people
1)Dont called **reloadData()** because you are adding particular number of rows so calling reloadData() will reload all data  and it will causes crash

2) Calling this method multiple times within the same **beginUpdates** and **endUpdates** block is allowed, and changes are processed incrementally

3)Most Important thing is indexSet must be within range
if you are Enter valid indexSet then The **numberOfRows** in the table view is automatically increased by the count of indexes.

4)you can select **animation** according to your need

**Sample Code :**

```
[yourTableView beginUpdates];  
NSIndexSet* theIndexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[self.yourTableContents count]-1];
[yourTableView insertRowsAtIndexes:theIndexSet withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationEffectFade];
[yourTableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct but first you have to insert the model object in the data source array to keep model and view in sync.

Comment: Add or insert? The order must be exactly the same. What error message do you get?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS...but i check index which is valid( not more than limit)

Comment: Are you aware that the index is zero-based? After you've added the item to the datasource array the index is `array.count -1`

Comment: @ vadian yes i know i added it at correct index, total count=15 and i value is 11 in my example

Comment: Anyway `insertRowsAtIndexes:withAnimation:` is the designated method to animate table view insertions. Set breakpoints or `NSLog` lines to monitor the value. Another point: If you're using `insertRowsAtIndexes` don't call `reloadData()`

Comment: yes sir I am not Calling reloadData() which also causes crash, But I don't know reason don't call reloadData() is there any specific reason behind that